# Spring Cloud gateway do not invoke the origin service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Im using the the spring cloud gateway for the first time. my service endpoint is `http://localhost:8080/student/getlist`

Problem is that when im trying to invoke my service using the cloud gateway it's giving me 404. the eureka is showing the service URL correctly

my gateway properties are below

```
spring.application.name=gateway
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
server.port=8085
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes.id=student-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes.uri=lb://student-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes.predicates.Path=/student/**
```

below is the actuator routes in gateway

```
[{"route_id":"CompositeDiscoveryClient_GATEWAY","route_definition":{"id":"CompositeDiscoveryClient_GATEWAY","predicates":[{"name":"Path","args":{"pattern":"/GATEWAY/**"}}],"filters":[{"name":"RewritePath","args":{"regexp":"/GATEWAY/(?<remaining>.*)","replacement":"/${remaining}"}}],"uri":"lb://GATEWAY","order":0},"order":0},{"route_id":"CompositeDiscoveryClient_STUDENT-SERVICE","route_definition":{"id":"CompositeDiscoveryClient_STUDENT-SERVICE","predicates":[{"name":"Path","args":{"pattern":"/STUDENT-SERVICE/**"}}],"filters":[{"name":"RewritePath","args":{"regexp":"/STUDENT-SERVICE/(?<remaining>.*)","replacement":"/${remaining}"}}],"uri":"lb://STUDENT-SERVICE","order":0},"order":0}]
```

im trying to invoke the service endpoint trough the gateway via

```
http://localhost:8085/student/getlist
```

above URL but this not working.
What am i doing wrong. there is no context path to any microservices.
sample code is under

```
https://github.com/ojith97/sample.git
```

Comment: `predicates` is service name?

Comment: no it is a some path value. Does it have to be service name in eureka?

Comment: yup, it should be service name in eueka

Comment: try that one as well not workiing

Comment: spring.application.name=gateway
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
server.port=8085
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
#spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lowerCaseServiceId=true



spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes.id=student-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes.uri=lb://student-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes.predicates.Path=/student-service/**

Comment: what is service name ?

Comment: `spring.cloud.gateway.routes.predicates.Path=/student-service/**`  should be `spring.cloud.gateway.routes.student-service.Path=/student/**` with `student-service` is service name in eureka, and /student/** is a path.

Comment: spring.application.name=gateway
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
server.port=8085
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
#spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lowerCaseServiceId=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes.id=student-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes.uri=lb://student-service
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes.predicates.Path=/student-service/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes.student-service.Path=/student/**

Comment: still  didnot work ? any error ?

Comment: above is the new one but its not working

Comment: no error only http 404

Comment: 404 means API it doesnot exsited, have you build `student-service` service, yet ?

Comment: yes it's giving me a response on

Comment: http://localhost:8080/student/getlist

Comment: the way that i feel is that the gateway do not route to the service

Comment: did you telnet `telnet localhost 8085` is connected or not ?

Comment: gateway is up and running on port 8085 and service is runnig on 8080 and eureka is running on 8761

Comment: no, I mean service is running or not ? port 8080

Comment: it's up and runniing

Comment: can you show service config file ? and `Application` name of the service in eureka ?

Answer (score 0):

Try change your properties to

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=student-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://student-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/student/**
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make the gateway aware of the eureka server with this

**eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://user:pass@localhost:8761/eureka**

And then make prevent the gateway register to eureka

**eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false**

The second option is important as it causes 404 errors with loadbalancing using lb:servicename structure.